# XML Schema: Setting fixed value for an attribute defined in a base-type

Tags: java, xml, web-services, wsdl, xsd

Is it possible to set an xml attribute's value to a fixed value when overriding a base type?

For example, my base type looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="Parameter" abstract="true">
  ... stuff that all parameters have in common ... 
  <xs:attribute name="parameterType" type="ax21:parameterType"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

The type *parameterType* is an enumeration with two possible values:

```
<xs:simpleType name="parameterType">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="singleParameter" />
      <xs:enumeration value="arrayParameter" />
   </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The *Parameter* type should not be used but only serves as a base for two complex-types extending it:

```
<xs:complexType name="ParameterImpl1">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ax21:Parameter">
                ...stuff specific for this implementation of parameter...
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ParameterImpl2">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ax21:WS_Parameter">
                ...stuff specific for this implementation of parameter...
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

And in those subtypes I'd like to set the *parameterType* attribute to a fixed value. 
Is there any possibility to do this?

In addition, I'd like to explain the background in my case - because I think there might be a simpler solution to my whole problem:
I'm writing a WSDL file and the *Parameter* type is used as an input-parameter in an operation. It is only used as an interface for the two types extending it but when processing the web-service request in my java server-side code(generated by Axis2) I only get an *Parameter* object and can't find any way to determine which of the two specific subtypes actually was passed in the request. 
(Except manually parsing the xmlString of the *Parameter* object, which I want to avoid)

Hopefully my explanations are precise enough - just tell me if you need additional information or don't understand what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
After additional research on this topic I think the only way to do something like this is using *Inheritance by Restriction* and *Polymorphism* as described in this article:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-flexschema/
So in that case the base-type contains the attribute and the inheriting classes 'override' it, setting a fixed value.

Comment: Sadly, the link from your update has broken since 2011.

Comment: There is an archived version at https://web.archive.org/web/20130731050042/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-flexschema/

Answer (score 1):

As you say this can be accomplished via restriction, the resulting XSD would look something like this

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2015 Developer Bundle Edition 12.1.2.5004 ([http://www.liquid-technologies.com][2])-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType abstract="true"
                    name="Parameter">
        <xs:attribute name="paramterType"
                      type="parameterType" />
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="parameterType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="singleParameter" />
            <xs:enumeration value="arrayParameter" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="ParameterImpl1">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="Parameter">
                <xs:attribute name="paramterType"
                              fixed="singleParameter"
                              type="parameterType" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ParameterImpl2">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="Parameter">
                <xs:attribute name="paramterType"
                              fixed="arrayParameter"
                              type="parameterType" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```